# GRUB not showing windows boot manager which is on another drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 in dual-boot.
My laptop has SSD and HDD both.
Windows is on the SSD whereas Ubuntu is on the HDD.
I made a separate EFI partition while installing Ubuntu using the `Something Else` option.

When I boot my laptop I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to enter GRUB and it does not show the `windows boot manager`. Moreover, Ubuntu is not detecting the SSD.

What to do ?
Please ask for any additional info required

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Have you turned off Windows fast start up? Are all drives set for AHCI? After you have confirmed you have done all that and if it still does not work, run this: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I haven't updated UEFI and SSD firmware. How do I do that for this install ? and what is AHCI ?

Comment: You go to your vendor's web site for support on your specific model system. It probably will say BIOS updates, but really is UEFI. And may say Windows, but is for system. If laptop they also should have SSD firmware update, or SSD vendor's support site. AHCI is an UEFI setting for your drives, please review your manual from vendor's support site.  What brand/model system? Many make it easier from within Windows.